# Fermat's little theorem question: why isn't $a^p \equiv 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, inverse

Fermat's little theorem says that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$.

I have kind of a stupid question. Since $p \equiv 0\pmod p $, why isn't $a^p \equiv a^0 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ ?

Comment: Because for $a=2, p=3$ that statement is not true. You seem to confuse modular equality with "regular" equality. Care to specify how you imply that last part of your question?

Comment: I just figured that because the two numbers are congruent, you could substitute them for one another, like in regular arithmetic.

Comment: Not sure whether or not you have taken some algebra before, but from an algebraic perspective, integers mod a prime form an abelian group under multiplication, and it has order $p-1$. Since $|x|$ divides  $|G|$ for finite groups, the result follows.

Comment: Multiplication and addition are group and field operations so replacing with equivalent congruence yield equivalences.  But power exponents are *not* a group or field operation but  a notation for integers regardless of the field values.... or more simply $a^{n \mod p} \not \equiv a^not \mod p \not \equiv (a \mod p)^n $ and there's no reason to think it should.

Comment: If $a \in G $ where G is a group whose elements can be ... anything... not nescessarily numbers, then $a^n = a*a*...*a $.  Note $n $ is *not* a member of the group but always a rational number, usually an integer.  $n $ *not* being a member of the group is not subject to group properties.  The a and other equivalence classes are subject to congruence but the powers $n $ are not.  Basically a and n live in two different universes. a is group member and n is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the modulo of the exponent like that. Think of $a^p$ as $\underbrace{a*a*\dots*a}_{p\text{ times}}$. If it was $p*a$ then what you did would be justified, but not with exponents. A full proof of Fermat's little theorem is off-topic, but this should answer your question!

--

*Edit to answer OP's comment on the original post:*

When in doubt you can always go back what $a = b \text{ (mod n)}$ means.

$$
\begin{align}
a = b \text{ (mod n)} \text{ is equivalent to } a = b + k * n \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
$$

From that it is easy to show that $n * a = 0 \text{ (mod n)}$:

$$
\begin{align}
n * a = b + k * n &\implies 0 = b + (k + a) * n\\
&\implies 0 = b \text{ (mod n)}
\end{align}
$$

But you can't do the same with $a^n$.

Comment: Thanks. The expansion makes the reason why you can't do it very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Modular arithmetic does not work that way. You cannot simply replace every occurence of $ p $ with $ 0 $ when working modulo $ p $.

The idea behind modular arithmetic is to take a set of elements (an ideal) in $ \mathbb{Z} $ and treat them as they are equal to 0. (I am being very loose with the terminology and the notions here, formalizing them requires some abstract algebra.) It turns out that the sets with which you can do this are sets which contain all integers divisible by some number $ n $, and we denote this set by $ n\mathbb{Z} $. Then, we define the set $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} $ as the set of all "shifted copies" of $ n\mathbb{Z} $ in the integers.

To fully understand what this means, let's consider the case $n = 3 $. Then,
 $$3\mathbb{Z} = \{ \ldots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \ldots \} $$
and we see that this set has three shifted copies in $ \mathbb{Z} $:

$$3\mathbb{Z} + 0 = \{ \ldots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \ldots \} $$
$$3\mathbb{Z} + 1 = \{ \ldots, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, \ldots \} $$
$$3\mathbb{Z} + 2 = \{ \ldots, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, \ldots \} $$

Note that, for example, $3\mathbb{Z} + 3 $ is the same set as $ 3\mathbb{Z}$. 
So, $ \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} = \{ 3\mathbb{Z}, 3\mathbb{Z} + 1, 3\mathbb{Z} + 2 \} $, which we may simply write as $ \{0, 1, 2\} $ if the context is clear. We then define addition and multiplication as follows:

$$ (a + n\mathbb{Z}) + (b + n\mathbb{Z}) = a + b + n\mathbb{Z} $$
$$ (a + n\mathbb{Z})(b + n\mathbb{Z}) = ab + n\mathbb{Z} $$

(One checks that these are well defined.) Now, for example working in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, we have that 
$$ (2 + 7\mathbb{Z})(5 + 7\mathbb{Z}) = 10 + 7\mathbb{Z} = 3 + 7\mathbb{Z} $$

which is actually the same thing as saying $ 2\cdot 5 \equiv 3 \pmod{7} $.

Now, we are ready to explain why exactly the logic in the OP does not work. The problem is that when we talk about $ x^p $ modulo p, we are really talking about $ (x + p\mathbb{Z})^p  = x^p + p\mathbb{Z}$. The base is a member of our structure $ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ where we have defined addition and multiplication, but the exponent is only telling us to multiply $ x + p\mathbb{Z} $ with itself $ p $ times. $ p $ is an integer and not a member of $ \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $, and for integers, the equality $ p = 0 $ is clearly not true. So, while $ p + p\mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z} $, we do not have that $ p = 0 $.

Answer (score 1):

While $x\equiv y\pmod p$ implies $a+x\equiv a+y\pmod p$ as well as $a\cdot x\equiv b\cdot y\pmod p$ (and even $x^a\equiv y^a\pmod p$), it does not imply $a^x\equiv a^y\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

As an intuitive counter example, Fermat's Little theorem in this form holds for all integers including zero. So $0^p \equiv 1 \mod p$ clearly does not work. If you are familiar with fields, you should realize you're staring at the additive identity, which we exclude from consideration in the multiplicative set.

A different question that should get you thinking about this: for any **non-zero integer** $a$ and prime $p$ then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$. For **any** integer $a$ and prime $p$ then $a^p \equiv a \mod p$. Find out how they are equivalent (hint: zero is the problem again).

Comment: Thanks -- I'd think it's because you can't have a multiplicative inverse of 0.

Comment: @Neel correct, since you would need $0\cdot a = 1$ and yet we have a zero axiom too that states $0 \cdot a = 0$. Satisfying both would be inconsistent :)